# Weird word breaks in table

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting, wordbreak

[image: 2 tables and 1 image. The image is what I want to recreate in a table]

The first table has these strange white spaces between the words and I really just do not understand how to get rid of them. I've used \raggedright, \sloppy and \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} but the results are all the same. I exported table 2 using the addin excel2latex.

Table 3 was made in an online table generator but I think I would need a microscope to read it. I am unable to change it to normal people sizing. Figure 1 is what I would like my final table to look like. Any help would be appreciated

%---------------------------------------------------------code table 2

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{bscam} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
 
\begin{table}[h]
         \centering
          \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{p{6em}p{9em}p{11em}p{10em}p{9em}p{11em}}
            \hline
            \textbf{Breath tool} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Primary mechanisms} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} & \textbf{Applications} \bigstrut\\
            \hline
            Rate & ↓ and/or paced BR & ↓ relative $V_{D}$; ANS regulation & ↑ perfusion; ↓ dyspnoea; and pacing assistance & ↑ $V_{T}$ at less-compliant lung volumes, initial air hunger & Novice runners; low-intensity exercise \bigstrut[t]\\
            Deep & ↑ $V_{T}$ via diaphragmatic engagement & ↓ BR; ↑ abdominal ribcage contribution to $V_{E}$ & ↓ WOB, LOV; ↑ postural control & Difficult to cue & Biofeedback; thoracic- dominant breathers \\
            Nose & Constant or intermittent nasal breathing & ↑ NO; ↑ air humidification, warming, and filtration & ↓ airway constriction; ↑ diaphragmatic activation & Difficult at high intensities; time required for habituation & Low intensity exercise; extreme climates \\
            Active exhale & Longer, forceful exhale phase with/without phonation & ↓ expiratory flow velocity: ↑ abdominal engagement, expiratory pressure, and NO & ↓ flow limitation, LOV; ↑ perfusion; and ANS regulation & ↓ relative TI; difficult to cue & Constant for calming effects; intermittent during high intensity or at altitude \\
            Sync & Step \& breath synchronization at whole- integer ratios & Step-driven flows; rhythmic entrainment & ↓ WOB; pacing assistance; hypnotic & Difficult to learn; even ratios ↑ side stitch & Odd ratios for ↓ side stitch; ↑ breath awareness \\
            Strength & Respiratory muscle resistance training & ↑ ventilatory muscle activation, metabolic stress & ↓ WOB, dyspnoea; ↑ diaphragmatic activation & Special equipment needed; unclear protocols & Low intensity exercise; training for competition \\
            Hold & Intermittent brief end- expiratory breath holds & ↑ biochemical stress, spleen contraction & ↓ chemosensitivity; cardiovascular performance & Risk of syncope, intense air hunger unpleasant & Pre-competition; elite sport \bigstrut[b]\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}%
        }
          \label{tab:breathingtechniques}%
          \caption{Overview Breath Tools \cite{Harbouretal}}
        \end{table}%
```

%------------------------------------------------------------------------code table 2

%------------------------------------------------------------------------code table 3

```
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Breath tool}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Primary   mechanisms}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Advantages}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Disadvantages}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Applications}} \\ \hline
Rate &
  ↓ and/or paced BR &
  ↓ relative VD; ANS regulation &
  ↑ perfusion; ↓ dyspnoea; and pacing assistance &
  ↑ VT at less-compliant lung volumes, initial air hunger &
  Novice runners; low-intensity exercise \\
Deep &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↑ VT via diaphragmatic\\      engagement\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↓ BR; ↑ abdominal   ribcage\\      contribution to VE\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↓ WOB, LOV; ↑ postural\\      control\end{tabular} &
  Difficult to   cue &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Biofeedback;   thoracic-\\      dominant breathers\end{tabular} \\
Nose &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Constant or   intermittent\\      nasal breathing\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↑ NO; ↑ air   humidification,\\      warming, and filtration\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↓ airway constriction; ↑\\      diaphragmatic activation\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Difficult at   high intensities;\\      time required for habituation\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Low intensity   exercise;\\      extreme climates\end{tabular} \\
Active exhale &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Longer,   forceful exhale phase with/without\\      phonation\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↓ expiratory flow velocity: ↑\\      abdominal engagement, expiratory pressure, and   NO\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↓ flow limitation, LOV; ↑\\      perfusion; and ANS regulation\end{tabular} &
  ↓ relative TI; difficult to cue &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Constant for   calming effects; intermittent during high\\      intensity or at altitude\end{tabular} \\
Sync &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Step \&   breath synchronization at whole-\\      integer ratios\end{tabular} &
  Step-driven   flows; rhythmic entrainment &
  ↓ WOB; pacing assistance; hypnotic &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Difficult to   learn; even ratios\\      ↑ side stitch\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Odd ratios   for ↓ side stitch; ↑\\      breath awareness\end{tabular} \\
Strength &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Respiratory   muscle\\      resistance training\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↑ ventilatory muscle\\      activation, metabolic stress\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↓ WOB, dyspnoea; ↑\\      diaphragmatic activation\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Special   equipment needed;\\      unclear protocols\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Low intensity   exercise;\\      training for competition\end{tabular} \\
Hold &
  Intermittent   brief end- expiratory breath holds &
  ↑ biochemical stress, spleen contraction &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}↓ chemosensitivity; \\      cardiovascular performance\end{tabular} &
  Risk of   syncope, intense air hunger unpleasant &
  Pre-competition;   elite sport
\end{tabular}%
}
```

%------------------------------------------------------------------------code table 3

Comment: don't use \resizebox on tabulars. It gives very irregular fontsizes.

Comment: You can add `\raggedright` to each cell with bad spacing (it resets after the cell), but there's a better way to accomplish that than typing it each time.  What kind of margins are you using?  With the default for article, it overflows in the middle of "Advantages", and leaves the page in the middle of "Disadvantages".  Or are you making a landscaped table?  And how is `\bigstrut` defined?

Comment: Welcome. // Please add your whole code from the preamble, i.e. starting with \documentclass until \begin{document} . Looks like you might be missing a package there.

Answer (score 2):

My main recommendation is that you employ landscape mode for the table. In the code below, this is accomplished by (a) loading the `rotating` package and (b) using the package's `sidewaystable` environment.

I would further recommend you employ a `tabularx` environment, set its width to `\textwidth`, and use a modified version of the `X` column type -- where the modification consists of suspending full justification -- for the five data columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,demo]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
%%\usepackage{bscam} % huh?
%%%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%%%%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
%%%%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%%\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}

% new:
\usepackage{amsmath,rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand{\mydash}{\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}}
\hyphenation{dys-pnoea dia-phrag-matic}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l LLLLL @{}}
\toprule
Breath tool & Description & Primary mechanisms & 
Advantages  & Disadvantages & Applications \\
\midrule
Rate & $\downarrow$~and/or paced BR 
     & $\downarrow$~relative $V_{D}$; ANS regulation 
     & $\uparrow$~perfusion; $\downarrow$~dyspnoea; and pacing assistance 
     & $\uparrow$~$V_{T}$ at less\mydash compliant lung volumes, initial air hunger 
     & Novice runners; low\mydash intensity exercise \\
Deep & $\uparrow$~$V_{T}$ via diaphragmatic engagement 
     & $\downarrow$~BR; $\uparrow$~abdominal ribcage contribution to $V_{E}$ 
     & $\downarrow$~WOB, LOV; $\uparrow$~postural control 
     & Difficult to cue 
     & Biofeedback; thoracic\mydash dominant breathers \\
Nose & Constant or intermittent nasal breathing 
     & $\uparrow$~NO; $\uparrow$~air humidification, warming, and filtration 
     & $\downarrow$~airway constriction; $\uparrow$~diaphragmatic activation 
     & Difficult at high intensities; time required for habituation 
     & Low intensity exercise; extreme climates \\
Active exhale 
     & Longer, forceful exhale phase with\slash without phonation 
     & $\downarrow$~expiratory flow velocity: $\uparrow$~abdominal engagement, expiratory pressure, and NO 
     & $\downarrow$~flow limitation, LOV; $\uparrow$~perfusion; and ANS regulation 
     & $\downarrow$~relative TI; difficult to cue 
     & Constant for calming effects; intermittent during high intensity or at altitude \\
Sync 
     & Step \& breath synchronization at whole\mydash integer ratios 
     & Step\mydash driven flows; rhythmic entrainment 
     & $\downarrow$~WOB; pacing assistance; hypnotic 
     & Difficult to learn; even ratios $\uparrow$~side stitch 
     & Odd ratios for $\downarrow$~side stitch; $\uparrow$~breath awareness \\
Strength 
     & Respiratory muscle resistance training 
     & $\uparrow$~ventilatory muscle activation, metabolic stress 
     & $\downarrow$~WOB, dyspnoea; $\uparrow$~diaphragmatic activation 
     & Special equipment needed; unclear protocols 
     & Low intensity exercise; training for competition \\
Hold & Intermittent brief end\mydash expiratory breath holds 
     & $\uparrow$~biochemical stress, spleen contraction 
     & $\downarrow$~chemosensitivity; cardiovascular performance 
     & Risk of syncope, intense air hunger unpleasant 
     & Pre\mydash competition; elite sport\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Overview Breath Tools \cite{Harbouretal}}
\label{tab:breathingtechniques}%
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Would you maybe know of a way to keep my dimensions of the table (Table 2), keep it in the portrait orientation but just to get rid of the white spaces?

Comment: @Radhika - To create the table in portrait mode instead of in landscape mode, just change `\begin{sidewaystable}` and `\end{sidewaystable}` to  `\begin{table}[p!]` and `\end{table}`, respectively. Do make sure, though, to use the `\mydash` macro instead of `-` ("ordinary dash") to connect compound words such as "thoracic-dominant" and "low-intensity".

Answer (score 1):

Using `tabularray` package, `\small` font size, and rotate table as suggested {Mico in his nice answer (+1):

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,demo]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{dys-pnoea dia-phrag-matic}
\usepackage{microtype}
%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\small
\begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt, 
             colspec= {@{} X[0.4,l] *{5}{X[l]} @{}},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
             rowsep = 3pt
             }
    \toprule
Breath tool & Description & Primary mechanisms &
Advantages  & Disadvantages & Applications \\
    \midrule
Rate & $\downarrow$~and/or paced BR
     & $\downarrow$~relative $V_{D}$; ANS regulation
     & $\uparrow$~perfusion; $\downarrow$~dyspnoea; and pacing assistance
     & $\uparrow$~$V_{T}$ at less compliant lung volumes, initial air hunger
     & Novice runners; low intensity exercise \\
Deep & $\uparrow$~$V_{T}$ via diaphragmatic engagement
     & $\downarrow$~BR; $\uparrow$~abdominal ribcage contribution to $V_{E}$
     & $\downarrow$~WOB, LOV; $\uparrow$~postural control
     & Difficult to cue
     & Biofeedback; thoracic dominant breathers \\
Nose & Constant or intermittent nasal breathing
     & $\uparrow$~NO; $\uparrow$~air humidification, warming, and filtration
     & $\downarrow$~airway constriction; $\uparrow$~diaphragmatic activation
     & Difficult at high intensities; time required for habituation
     & Low intensity exercise; extreme climates \\
Active exhale
     & Longer, forceful exhale phase with\slash without phonation
     & $\downarrow$~expiratory flow velocity: $\uparrow$~abdominal engagement, expiratory pressure, and NO
     & $\downarrow$~flow limitation, LOV; $\uparrow$~perfusion; and ANS regulation
     & $\downarrow$~relative TI; difficult to cue
     & Constant for calming effects; intermittent during high intensity or at altitude \\
Sync
     & Step \& breath synchronization at whole integer ratios
     & Step driven flows; rhythmic entrainment
     & $\downarrow$~WOB; pacing assistance; hypnotic
     & Difficult to learn; even ratios $\uparrow$~side stitch
     & Odd ratios for $\downarrow$~side stitch; $\uparrow$~breath awareness \\
Strength
     & Respiratory muscle resistance training
     & $\uparrow$~ventilatory muscle activation, metabolic stress
     & $\downarrow$~WOB, dyspnoea; $\uparrow$~diaphragmatic activation
     & Special equipment needed; unclear protocols
     & Low intensity exercise; training for competition \\
Hold & Intermittent brief end expiratory breath holds
     & $\uparrow$~biochemical stress, spleen contraction
     & $\downarrow$~chemosensitivity; cardiovascular performance
     & Risk of syncope, intense air hunger unpleasant
     & Pre competition; elite sport\\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\caption{Overview Breath Tools \cite{Harbouretal}}
\label{tab:breathingtechniques}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is some analysis and some trials to approach your desired result a little bit more. All changes where done with the questions in mind "does it compile?" and "do I move into the right direction?"

1. I introduced package `babel`, which takes care of hyphenation in the specified language. Package `booktab` is recommended for books.
2. To narrow down your problem I disabled all (or most) of the packages whcih are not needed to show the problem in the tables.
3. Though up- and down-arrows are shown in your screenshots, I don't see them in my compile. Instead there is some extra white space. What's missing is using the Latex predefined `\textuparrow` and `\textdownarrow`. For simplicity I introduced two new commands `\tup` and `\tdn`, which I used in your table entries.
4. I'm not an expert in tables, and this part can certainly be done much better. However, I reduced the width of the table manually, had to keep away the `\bigstrut` commands, and commented out (i.e. deleted) `\centering` and `\resizebox`. // I also tailered down the number of rows for better overview. (In fact, the bigstrut-problem was hidden in the vast amount of content; so stepwise radical deletion and small re-insertions paved the way (failing new content means: trouble maker is here))
5. Because `babel` is working on hyphenation, I deliberately removed many (if not all) of your hyphens.

I suggest to consult some introduction on Latex to learn more about the ways of `Tex` and `Latex` to fill in spaces for "a good look". To some extent you can influence it via a penalty-mechanism, but the basic idea has been from the start "write text, and let Tex do the placement" ... which works fine many times, but not always.

I also suggest to have a closer look at tables, not only the traditional ones which come with Latex, but also at ctan: https://www.ctan.org/topic/table .

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}% takes care of language specific hyphenation
\usepackage{booktabs}% recommended for books

% --- diabling packages, which aren't neede for this problem ---
\usepackage{helvet}
    %\usepackage{bscam} % missing // what is is?
    %\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    %\usepackage{subcaption}
    %\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
    %\usepackage{pdflscape}
    %\usepackage{longtable}% used correctly below?
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
    %\usepackage{lscape}
    %\usepackage{todonotes}% needed for the table?
    %\usepackage{placeins}% needed for the table?
    %\usepackage{geometry}
    %\usepackage{tikz}
    %\usepackage{adjustbox}
    %\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
    %\usepackage{xcolor}
    %\usepackage{sectsty}% relevant to change fonts of sections

% --- abbreviations -------
\newcommand\tup{\textuparrow{}}% arrow up
\newcommand\tdn{\textdownarrow{}}% arrow down


\begin{document}

\tup{} \tdn{}

\begin{table}[h]
 %        \centering
%          \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
 %           \begin{tabular}{p{6em}p{9em}p{11em}p{10em}p{9em}p{11em}}
          \begin{tabular}{p{4em}p{6em}p{7em}p{7em}p{6em}p{6em}}
 %            \begin{tabular}{llllll}
      \hline
            \textbf{Breath tool} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Primary mechanisms} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} & \textbf{Applications} \\%\bigstrut\\% <<< bigstruct seems to be wrong here
            \hline
% replacing the copied arrow by Latex-definitions
           Deep & \tup{} $V_{T}$ via diaphragmatic engagement & \tdn{} BR; \tup{} abdominal ribcage contribution to $V_{E}$ & \tdn{} WOB, LOV; \tup{} postural control & Difficult to cue & Biofeedback; thoracic-dominant breathers \\
 
            Hold & Intermittent brief end-expiratory breath holds & \tup{} biochemical stress, spleen contraction & \tdn{} chemosensitivity; cardiovascular performance & Risk of syncope, intense air hunger unpleasant & Precompetition; elite sport\\% \bigstrut[b]\\
            \hline
 
            \end{tabular}%
%        }
          \label{tab:breathingtechniques}%
          \caption{Overview Breath Tools \cite{Harbouretal}}% this citation points to nowhere
        \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may also wany to suspend full justification in the narrow columns

Comment: I'd say that `booktabs` are recommended for any data table, not just in book.